# Ignore physics after collision in unity3d(2d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

How can I force Unity to not change the speed and direction of objects after collision?  I need to get `OnCollisionEnter2d` event, but I don't need to automatically change speed and direction;  I want to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to get OnCollisionEnter2d event, but i dont need to
>   automatically change speed and direction, because i want to do it
>   manually

If you don't want to affect the Object when it collides with another Object, you need to mark the Collider as Trigger.

[image]

After this, use the trigger function instead of the collision functions.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{

}
```

It will detect that the Objects collided it won't move them. You can then manually move them however you want.

Comment: But i need to get Collision2D to build a reflect vector manually, in OnTriggerEnter2D there is no collision - only collider.

Comment: You don't need `Collision2D` to build a reflect vector manually, Why do you need it? You can edit and post your reflector code in your question.

Comment: I need to get standart Vector3.Reflect(oldVector, normalized). But i have no normalized vector without Collision2D - how can i get it?

Comment: You complained that you need Collider2D. I asked you to post the reflect code that uses Collision2D and you refused to do so. What you posted above has nothing to do with Collision2D and don't see how that is using Collision2D. Note that this question has answered the question asked in the title. You can create new question if that's something unrelated. Happy coding!