# Get ContactPoint2D/contact normal from the OnTriggerXXX function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to force Unity to not change the speed and direction of objects after collision. I need to get `OnCollisionEnter2D` event, but I don't need Unity to automatically change speed and direction; I want to do it manually.

I tried to use this code but that dont work (automatically collision still works):

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    fallVector = GetRigidbody.velocity.normalized;
    fallNormalVector = collision.contacts[0].normal;

    var reflectedVelocity = Vector3.Reflect(fallVector, fallNormalVector).normalized;
    GetRigidbody.velocity = reflectedVelocity * 3;        
}
```

I was told to mark my GameObject as `isTrigger` and use `OnTriggerEnter2D` from my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773283/ignore-physics-after-collision-in-unity3d2d) question but it uses `Collider2D` instead of `Collision2D` and I can't get the contact normal from that.

How can I get `ContactPoint2D` or contact normal from `Collider2D` in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function?

**EDIT:**

After reading the answer below, I wrote this code below, but `GetContacts()` returns (0.0, 0.0) in all elements , what I did wrong?
Both objects of collision IsTrigger = true. (Unity version is 5.6.0f3)

```
ContactPoint2D[] contacts = new ContactPoint2D[2];

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //Get all contact points and save to the contacts array variable
    collision.GetContacts(contacts);

    Vector3 normal = contacts[0].normal;

    GetRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.Reflect(GetRigidbody.velocity, normal);
}
```

Comment: Colliders with `isTrigger = true` don't return contact points. So far it seems there are not trivial way to get the same contact points as with normal colliders without writing some custom raycasting code, and it's hard to get that right for non-trivial collider shapes.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't use OnTriggerEnter2D - it have no Collision2D to define
>   contact normal

<strike>The normal variable is from the [`ContactPoint2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint2D.html) structure and you **can** translate `OnCollisionEnter2D` code into `OnTriggerEnter2D` and still be able to retrieve that information with the [`Collider2D.GetContacts`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.GetContacts.html) function.</strike>

You must have *Unity 5.6* and older in order to use this function. Please don't say *"it doesn't work"* if you don't have this version because it shouldn't. You need to update to get this feature.

*With Collision*:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Vector2 normal = collision.contacts[0].normal;
    Vector2 point = contacts[0].point;
}
```

*The Trigger equivalent*:

```
//Variable to hold the contacts
ContactPoint2D[] contacts = new ContactPoint2D[2];

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //Get all contact points and save to the contacts array variable
    collision.GetContacts(contacts);

    Vector3 normal = contacts[0].normal;
    Vector2 point = contacts[0].point;
}
```

Make sure to mark the colliders as triggers first, as said in my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773936/3785314) answer. The only thing that needs to be changed inside the code in your function is `fallNormalVector = collision.contacts[0].normal;`.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

*You can't do this anymore* or something changed. This post was made with Unity 5.6 and it worked at the time this was tested. The `Collider2D.GetContacts` [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.GetContacts.html) at that time didn't say it would't work when collider is marked as `isTrigger`. The latest [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.GetContacts.html) says that it can't be done.

> Contacts involving a Collider2D set to be a trigger will never be
>   returned here as trigger colliders do not have contact points.

This was tested before being posting and it worked fine and now I suspect that it was a bug when it worked while Collider is marked as `isTrigger`. *To use `Collider2D.GetContacts`, make sure your Collider is **not** marked as `isTrigger`.*

Comment: Have you tried this code? All my experiments, googling and fragments of Unity documentation point to that if one or both of the colliders is a trigger then it does not provide contact points. `collision.GetContacts()` then returns a count of `0`.

Comment: @angularsen I did test it before posting it. I test 99 percent of code in my answer before posting. See my EDIT for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your GetContacts code is behaving correctly, however [based on the ContactPoint2D documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint2D.html), Triggers do not generate Contact Points. If you were to run `int count = other.GetContacts(contacts);` the `count` variable should be set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

One method you could use to get a point *close* to the collision point is to use `collider2D.ClosestPoint(transform.position)`. This would get a point on the collider that is closest to the current transforms position.

There could be inaccuracies with this approach, but might be good enough depending on the use case.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.ClosestPoint.html